# Convert string to LINQ query

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

which method or way should be used to convert a string to a linq query ?

Environment: VS 2010/C#

Comment: What sort of string? What do you mean by "linq query" ?

Comment: Please give us more information... From all you wrote, I would just answer `String.ToLinqQuery()`.

Comment: String.ToLinqQuery() does not exist
-Captain Obvious

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of what you are trying to achieve but if you are referring to creating linq queries from strings you could use the dynamic linq library, check it out here http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You have to do something like this:

```
var query =
                db.Customers.Where("Country== @0 and Orders.Count >= @1", "Costa Rica", 10).
                OrderBy("CompanyName").
                Select("New(CompanyName as Name, Phone)");
```

some parts could be taken from strings, some others (tables) cant

Answer (score 0):

Converting a string to Linq query isn't directly possibly with out some parsing and translation into `System.Linq.Expression` objects. Neither is trivial.

Check [this out for one example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/QueryAnything.aspx).