# Errors say that an expression must be of CollectionType.

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

As my title said, I'm having troubles with trying to make some entity SQL requests.

The whole code here has to be used as a search engine. I need to build strings and then, convert them into queries. I had already done everything with linq-to-sql. But it seems impossible to convert a string into a linq query. However, I found on stackoverflow a kind of solution, but I've never been able to use it : [String.ToLinqQuery()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179084/convert-string-to-linq-query). It's just not known by visual studio, and I can't find any documentation about it.

Although, here's the error I get :

> The specified expression must be of CollectionType. Near parenthesized expression, line 1, column 20.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.EntitySqlException: The specified expression must be of CollectionType. Near parenthesized expression, line 1, column 20.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 145:        Meetings
>   Line 146:
>   Line 147:            @For Each meeting In Model.Meetings
>   Line 148:                   @
>
>   @meeting.date
>   Line 149:                   @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Meeting", New With {.id = meeting.idmeeting}, "Null")

And here is all my code: Controller:

```
  Imports System.Data.Objects
  Imports System.Linq.Expressions

  Namespace MvcApplication4
   Public Class SearchController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    <HttpPost()>
    Function Index(search As String, choix As Integer) As ActionResult
        Dim test As Integer = Request("choix")
        Dim chaine As String = Request("searchString")
        Dim message As String = "message"

        Dim requete As String = "Select value p FROM('db.meeting') as p where p.compteRendu LIKE '%chaine%'"
        Dim meetings = New ObjectQuery(Of meeting)(requete, db)

        Dim model = New SearchModel With {
            .Meetings = meetings,
            }
        Return View(model)
    End Function
   End Class
  End Namespace
```

model:

```
  Public Class SearchModel
     Public Property Meetings As IEnumerable(Of meeting)
  End Class
```

View:

```
  @Modeltype MvcApplication4.SearchModel

   @<fieldset>
    <legend>Meetings</legend>
         @For Each meeting In Model.Meetings
               @<ul> @meeting.date 
               @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Meeting", New With {.id = meeting.idmeeting}, "Null") </ul>
               @<li> @Html.Raw(meeting.compteRendu.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "<br />"))</li>
         Next meeting
    </fieldset>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is a part of my .edmx model

```
<EntityType Name="meeting">
      <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="idmeeting" />
      </Key>
      <Property Name="idmeeting" Type="int" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
      <Property Name="FK_meet_client" Type="int" />
      <Property Name="FK_meet_contact" Type="int" />
      <Property Name="FK_meet_opport" Type="int" />
      <Property Name="FK_meet_user" Type="int" />
      <Property Name="compteRendu" Type="longtext" />
      <Property Name="date" Type="datetime" />
      <Property Name="adresse" Type="text" />
    </EntityType>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not really found a solution. I Used another way to work with my searches, using a predicatebuilder for Linq.

the code of the predicatebuilder has been taken (and translated to VB) from http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Here is the code of the predicatebuilder in VB

```
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Linq.Expressions
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module PredicateBuilder
Sub New()
End Sub
Public Function [True](Of T)() As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))
    Return Function(f) True
End Function
Public Function [False](Of T)() As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))
    Return Function(f) False
End Function

<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
Public Function [Or](Of T)(expr1 As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean)), expr2 As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))) As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))
    Dim invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast(Of Expression)())
    Return Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))(Expression.[OrElse](expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters)
End Function

<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
Public Function [And](Of T)(expr1 As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean)), expr2 As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))) As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))
    Dim invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast(Of Expression)())
    Return Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))(Expression.[AndAlso](expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters)
End Function
End Module
```

And here is how I used it :

```
        Dim predicate1 = PredicateBuilder.False(Of meeting)()
        For Each mot In tabMot
            predicate1 = predicate1.Or(Function(m) m.compteRendu.Contains(mot))
        Next
        Dim meetings = db.meeting.AsExpandable().Where(predicate1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The FROM part in your ESQL query seems wrong. Try to use:

```
Select value p FROM db.meeting as p where p.compteRendu LIKE '%chaine%'
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything. I think it's because I don't get a collection, but I don't know howto...

Comment: So it most probably means that `db.meeting` is not valid name of entity set in your model.

Comment: When I used Linq, my queries worked well. I've changed because I needed something more dynamical. I think that the problem might be inside the parameters of the "ObjectQuery".

Comment: But the name of the entity set in LINQ is not same as the name in the CSDL part of your mapping. ESQL uses the name from CSDL. You will find it in your EDMX file.

Comment: I've got a solution, but I still need 3 hours before I can answer it. I hope I'll not forget.

Comment: Your posted snippet contains only entity set definition but you must also find what prefix to use. You are using `db` - is it name of the container in your EDMX?